# better design than circular dependency for convertible types

Tags: c++, dependencies, c++11, circular-dependency

I have come across code that has two classes that should be convertible between each other and the design was to provide single argument constructor for each class taking the other class, e.g., in file `A.hpp`

```
class B;
class A
{
  explicit A( const B& );
  ...
};
```

and in `B.hpp`

```
class A;
class B
{
  explicit B( const A& );
  ...
};
```

which introduces a circular dependency between the two classes (which I'd rather avoid but maybe it's not a big deal).  Is there a better design?  A *different* design would be to have another converter class that could do this work, e.g. in `C.hpp`

```
#include "A.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"
class C
{
  static A toA( const B& );
  static B toB( const A& );
  ...  
};
```

or namespace scoped functions, e.g. in `D.hpp`

```
#include "A.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"
namespace D
{
  A toA( const B& );
  B toB( const A& );
  ...
}
```

but I'm not convinced either of those are *better*.  Is there a clearly better alternative to any of these solutions?

Comment: We're missing a lot of details. For what it's worth, if the `static` and free functions are a viable solution, then those constructors should probably be `explicit`. My gut instinct would be to go with the constructors despite the circular dependency. It's best to declare each conversion in its class' respective header.

Comment: You haven't stated how that circular dependency is a problem. Forward declaration of the other class typically solves it just fine.

Comment: These allow implicit conversions both ways between two different types — something I'd strongly question. The circular coupling introduced through those constructors is just expressing the coupling that the (hopefully) close relationship between the two classes represent. If I were you, I'd ask: Why do I have to have two classes? Why are they so closely related? And do I really, really, really feel I need _implicit_ conversions? (In the last >15 years, every piece of code that had implicit conversions and lived long enough had me remove them later, since they caused unexpected trouble.)

Comment: @Grizzly: It solves the problem of getting the constructor declarations to compile. In their definitions, these two classes still depend on each other circularly.

Comment: @sbi the example I am looking at is a kinematic state estimate where class A encapsulates position and velocity while class B position, velocity and acceleration.  B can be made an A by dropping the acceleration terms and A can be made a B by adding all zero acceleration terms.  However, the algorithms that work on the types differ significantly depending on whether the class is an A or a B.

Comment: @Patatoswatter explicit constructors are fine for this example so I'll change that so people don't focus on that aspect of the question.

Comment: @Grizzly I typically try to avoid them in general but I did mention in my question that they might not be a big deal in this case; however, what if I had a whole alphabet of classes: then probably a utility class or namespace would be better than having A-Z all depend on each other, no?

Answer (score 3):

I think it is possible to leave one of the two types alone and use the other class to convert to and from that other type:

```
class A {};

class B {
public:
    B(A a) { ... }
    operator A() const { ... }
};
```

This way a `B` can be constructed from an `A` and a `B` can be converted into an `A`.

Comment: That is a possible difference: do you believe it is better?

Comment: Generally, I tend to avoid implicit conversions in the first place. Is it better than a circular dependency? yes. Is it better than explicit conversion functions somewhere? depends on how the classes are to be used

Comment: +1 This would be my choice.  Though to match with the OP's code, both the `B(A)` constructor and the `operator A` should be marked `explicit`.  Being able to say `explicit operator A` is new with C++11 and imho is a huge advance for generic code.  Previously we had `toA()` and `toB()`, which doesn't work well with generic code.  But now, with explicit conversion operators, we have `static_cast<A>(b)` and `static_cast<B>(a)`.  I.e. we now have a **generic** syntax for explicit conversions that works even in the context presented by this question! :-)

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Is there a particular reason you would prefer this to a pair of constructors, or is it only better in the context of eliminating circular dependency? The constructors are symmetric and consistent… here we have to remember which class implements which conversion, and if we need to `friend` the conversion functions, that re-introduces the dependency.

Comment: @Potatoswatter:  I find this pattern helpful in the context of eliminating circular dependencies.  In the absence of circular dependencies I typically prefer constructors over conversion operators (all other considerations being equal).  The reason?  <shrug>  Probably just familiarity.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Two constructors would also require you to be the author of both classes, which isn't exactly always possible. The new `explicit` conversion operators are really a big step forward.

Answer (score 1):

Circular dependency is not in itself a bad thing, as long as it makes sense in the real-world scenario that you are modeling. For example, if two classes, `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger`, both represent numbers (presumably, using different representation), it makes sense to let one to be constructed from the other, and let it go both ways.

Adding a third class may be a better option, but only if using it does not force you into the "friendship" territory, or forces you to write materially inferior code to avoid "friendship" declarations. Syntax would become less "fluent", too. Sometimes, it is a good thing, for example, when you convert strings to numbers. But there are times when the extra `convert_to` is annoying, for example, when you construct C++ strings from C strings (but not the other way around).

Ultimately, it boils to the ability of your library users to communicate their intentions in the most comprehensive way. Introduction of circular dependencies among classes should be secondary to this goal.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments,

> I typically try to avoid them in general but I did mention in my question that they might not be a big deal in this case; however, what if I had a whole alphabet of classes: then probably a utility class or namespace would be better than having A-Z all depend on each other, no?

If you have a large number of interconvertible classes, you should provide a common interface among them (or try to provide one for a large subset). Then define a templated constructor,

```
class A
{
  template< typename other > // one template instead of many functions
  explicit A( const other &arg, // user just passes by reference as usual
      typename enable_if< // SFINAE restricts template to proper cases
      other::implements_common_interface, // trait signals such cases
      int >::type = 0 ) { // only generate a dummy parameter
      ; // define implementation in header, as with any template
  } // dependency is resolved when template is used, i.e. called

  enum { implements_common_interface = true }; // define trait
};
```

Now all the classes sharing the common interface, and defining `implements_common_interface = true`, can be converted to each other without any explicit dependency.

Comment: I really like this approach to the more general case.

Comment: Minor nitpick: I think you might be missing a '*' in the enable_if use.

Comment: @bluescarni: If I hadn't specified `int` as the second template argument, I would need a `*` to form `void*` instead of `void` which cannot be a parameter type. I admit I didn't test this code but that shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

As long as both constructors are `explicit`, I don't see a problem. These are *not* implicit conversions so they are pretty safe.

BTW, This kind of circular dependency is a generalization of recursive definitions such as this one:

```
struct List {
  List(List * next) : _next(next) {}
  List * _next;
};
```

Here `List` is defined in terms of `List` and is constructed from a `List`. Your classes are an example of mutual recursion. Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score -1):

Here's one alternative that allows polymorphic stuff on both objects:

```
void convert_to_b(const A &a, B &b);
void convert_to_a(const B &b, A &a);
```

This would just transfer data between A and B, and it can call member functions of both to do it's job.

Comment: As what?  Global scope functions?

Comment: Then you have to default-construct and modify the destination object. You just added the requirement of default construction and increased overhead. What was gained?

Comment: And polymorphism on the destination objects will result in slicing and invalid values. Yes, you need to default construct the destination if you intend to use these to initialize something.

Comment: it doesn't need any slicing or invalid values. (A's and B's interface should be correct so that it allows this operation)

Comment: Oh then, so no "polymorphic stuff"?

Comment: the polymorphic stuff is in the references. The interface of A and B does not need to know all the data of derived classes to be able to do the conversion.